# Laravel Resultados de uma Query Builder para eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo uma consulta usando o Query Builder

```
$users = DB::select( DB::raw("
SELECT users.* from users, permissions_customers WHERE
permissions_customers.customer_id in 
(
  SELECT permissions_customers.customer_id from 
  permissions_customers
  WHERE 
  permissions_customers.user_id = ?
)
AND
permissions_customers.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
"), array(5));
```

Como vocês podem ver no T-SQL o retorno é um resultado da tabela users, porem ele me retorna um array de Objetos do tipo stdClass, eu gostaria que esses resultados fossem um lista(Collection) de Eloquent Model pra mim poder acessar seus métodos de relação, eu consegui fazer um loop nos resultados e coloca-los em uma Collection mas mas quando eu tento criar um Objeto Eloquent Model a partir do meu objeto stdClass, o Eloquent model parece não funcionar como deveria não consigo fazer consultas nos métodos de relação

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma seria selecionar somente os ids dos usuário em sua query builder e montar um array com o resultado

```
// users.* alterei para users.id
$users = DB::select( DB::raw("
    SELECT users.id from users, permissions_customers etc...etc...
    GROUP BY users.id
"), array(5));

$users_ids = (array) $users; // talvez não funcione esta linha
```

Em seguida fazer uma chamada ao model User pois assim teria acesso às relações.

```
$users = Users::whereIn('id', $users_ids)->get();
```

Mas isso vai gerar mais queries do que precisaria.
Usar Eloquent é uma opção de praticidade de código mas às vezes tem a consequência de aumento no número de queries.